# java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String?

Tags: java, jtable, sqldatatypes

***I am trying to add row values of datatype(money) in which zeros after decimal are automatically formed in Jtable like these
55.0000
28.0000
60.0000
20.0000
50.0000***

on runtime log showing this error

> java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Here is the code for rows addition from Jtable

```
        double total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<table.getRowCount(); i++){
            double amount = Double.parseDouble((String) table.getValueAt(1, 6) );
            total+=amount;
        }
        totalSum.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

*

### Is there any way to add float type values??

  *

Comment: `table.getValueAt(1, 6)` already returns a `BigDecimal`, why do you think you need to cast it to `String`?  What's wrong with using `BigDecimal.doubleValue()`?

Comment: You can reliably convert objects to strings using `object.toString()` (assuming `object` isn't null).

Comment: Jim Garrison, sir can you please give me a precise solution.

Comment: and, BTW, you're always getting the value of the same cell (1,6). I guess you meant table.getValueAt(i, 6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); ++i) {
    final BigDecimal amount = (BigDecimal)table.getValueAt(i, 6);
    total = total.add(amount);
}
totalSum.setText(total.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
double amount = Double.parseDouble((String) table.getValueAt(1, 6) );
```

to

```
double amount = table.getValueAt(1, 6).doubleValue();
```

There's no need to convert a `BigDecimal` to `String` just to make a `double`.

Comment: @KamranAshiq All the compiler knows is that `getValueAt()` is an `Object`.  Apparently the method is defined with `Object` as the return type.  If the method will really return a `BigDecimal` in this case you can cast it to a `BigDecimal` and then use `doubleValue()`: `((BigDecimal)table.getValueAt(1,6)).doubleValue()`.  This only works if the object it returns really is a `BigDecimal`.  It won't convert anything else to a `BigDecimal`.  Instead, you'll get an exception if it's not the right type.

Comment: Yes, but I think you should point out this loses precision: you can do it only with BigDecimal, and not have this issue.