# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, spring, list, hibernate, collections

I am trying to iterate a list which contains multiple Ids like this:

[148066, 148065, 148064, 148063, 148062, 148061, 148060, 148059, 148058, 148057, 148056]

```
List<String> list= DbService.getPayUVerificationList();
```

where this above list object contains all the fetched Ids from DB.

```
 if(null != list && !list.isEmpty())
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            //System.out.println(list.get(i));
            //String txnId= list.get(i).toString();
            //String txnId = (String) list.get(i);
           //String txnId = (String) list.get(i);
            String txnId = (String) list.get(i).toString();
            String output=hdfcService.checkPayStatusByPayU(txnId);
        }
   }
```

but i am getting

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String

I have tried lot of casting and approaches but all in vain.

**Edit 1:** As many are saying that this "list.get(i).toString()" should work but in my case this is still not working and i have no idea about this.

Comment: `String txnId = String.valueOf(list.get(i))`?

Comment: This is nothing but `list.get(i).toString()` itself, which the OP has already tried. Ideally it should work

Comment: @nirmalsharma at which line is the error coming?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686654/java-math-bigdecimal-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-string)

Answer (score 3):

`String txnId = (String) list.get(i).toString();` should be `String txnId = String.valueOf(list.get(i))`

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
String.valueOf(list.get(i))
```

Which is essentially nothing but

```
list.get(i).toString()
```

So, what you've tried already should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

instead of below, you should not use toString(), its already declared as a "String"

```
  String txnId = (String) list.get(i).toString();
```

Do this:

```
 String txnId = (String) list.get(i);
```

Or

```
 String txnId = String.valueOf(list.get(i))
```

Comment: list.get(i).toString() is still not working but later worked.